# Delete Request with Axios... getting Bad request

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-delete

my delete request is getting a 404. I´m using the id for deleting each card but I´m getting undefined, even though the id is a property of the object. I would appreciate any help or ideas. This is my function:

```
const DeletePlayer = async (id) => {
    
    try{let res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/players/${id}`);
    console.log("Player was deleted",res);
      }catch(err){
    console.log("there was an error", err)
  }
```

---

this is the mock backend:

```
id  1
realName    "Brianna Forbes"
playerName  "Dreamlurk The Unstoppable"
asset   "Foghammer Lead"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing `id` in your query parameter. This would be ok for GET method, but for DELETE you need to supply `body` to the request (same as with POST or PUT). You should send your API call like so:

```
const DeletePlayer = async (id) => {
    try {
        let res = await axios.delete("http://localhost:8000/players", {
            data: { id }; // same as { id: id }
        });
        console.log("Player was deleted",res);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("there was an error", err)
    }
}
```

And then your `id` variable will be accessible on the server under request's `body`